# Debug Apollo Server as AWS Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda, apollo-server

I followed the directions at Apollo Server for deploying as AWS lambda. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/
used the serverless framework and it is working fine in region east-2.

I extended the example to use a PostGres DB for queries (I used the npm sequalize package). The same code is used fine when I run as an ApolloServer and a local postresql DB. I made it so that it can also switch to an apollo-server-lambda. I have an if statement that changes the connection to the DB depending on if it is a lambda or not.

The issue I have is that queries that do not hit the DB work fine. But graphql queries to the DB return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Internal server error"
  }
}
```

OK, So now how do I debug a nodejs lambda function?

The lambda management console does have a test operation. I redefiend the hello world test to use this as the test:

```
{
  "operationName": null,
  "variables": {},
  "query": "{users {id firstName lastName addressNumber streetName city email createdAt updatedAt }}"
}
```

But that does not seem to be the right way to invoke the lambda function. Because the log returns:

```
{
  "body": "Apollo Server supports only GET/POST requests.",
  "statusCode": 405,
  "headers": {
    "Allow": "GET, POST"
  }
}
```

---

---

### server.js

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')
const { ApolloServer: ApolloServerLambda } = require('apollo-server-lambda')
const { typeDefs, resolvers, connect } = require('./schema.js')

// The ApolloServer constructor requires two parameters: your schema
// definition and your set of resolvers.

async function setup(server) {
  let { url } = await server.listen()
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`)
  await connect("local")
}

async function awsSetup() {
  await connect("aws")
}

if (process.env.USERNAME == 'ysg4206') {
  const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
  setup(server)
} else {
  const server = new ApolloServerLambda({ typeDefs, resolvers })
  //awsSetup()
  exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler({
    playground: true,
    introspection: true,
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      credentials: true,
    },
    context: ({ event, context }) => { return (
      {
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context
      })
    }
  })
}
```

---

### schema.js

```js
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')
const { DB } = require('./db')
const { GraphQLDateTime } = require('graphql-iso-date')

exports.typeDefs = gql`
  scalar DateTime

  type User {
    id: Int
    "English First Name"
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    addressNumber: Int
    streetName: String
    city: String
    email: String
    createdAt: DateTime
    updatedAt: DateTime
  }

  input UserType {
    "Hebrew First Name"
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    addressNumber: Int
    streetName: String
    city: String
    email: String
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User]
    findUser(firstName: String): User
    hello(reply: String): String
  }

  type Mutation {
    addUser(user: UserType): User!
  }

  type Subscription {
    newUser: User!
  }
`

exports.resolvers = {
  Query: {
    // users: async () => {
    //   let users = await DB.findAll()
    //   return users
    // },
    users: () => DB.findAll(),
    findUser: async (_, { firstName }) => {
      let who = await DB.findFirst(firstName)
      return who
    },
    hello: (_, { reply }, context) => {
      console.log(`hello with reply ${reply}`)
      console.log(`context : ${JSON.stringify(reply, null, 4)}`)
      return reply
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    addUser: async (_, args) => {
      let who = await DB.addUser(args.user)
      return who
    }
  }
}

exports.connect = async function connect(where) {
  await DB.dbSetup(where)
  await DB.populate()
  let users = await DB.findAll()
  console.log(users)
}
```

Comment: Does your database instance configured in vpc?

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale yes it has the default VPC. And this is where I need more training. Since I don't yet grok the vpc security groups, and how/if to get the lambda function on the same VPC, and how Public affects this. (I know the theory, but not the AWS specifics).

Comment: Ok, I setup the security groups and subnets for lambda to get to the PostGreSQL db. But now I get a 3D000 error from PG, which means DB does not exist. But II can see it in RDS, and I am providing the name of the connection.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale I think I am happy with the debug process. So I forked a new thread for figuring out the DB connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919590/aws-lambda-connect-via-pg-js-to-rds-postgres-database-connection-made-no-timeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging lambda functions is hard! You can try digging through logs if they are configured through CloudWatch, but that won't always give you a workable stack trace, and it's challenging to find the exact invocation you're looking for.

Have you tried deploying with the Serverless Framework Dashboard? That will help give you a full stack trace along with your logs. You can get started by simply running the `serverless` command in your application root directory.

More information is available [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/dashboard/)

Full disclosure - I work for Serverless Inc. on the Serverless Framework.

Comment: I like what you have in the dashboard. But I am not seeing anything in from the console.log() statements. I have included the basic Apollo server.js (not the DB or the schema). Is there something I should be doing to see the logs? I have put almost every permission in the role.

Comment: Interesting! Is the function being called at all? Each invocation includes the full logs generated by the function. If there's no stack trace, and the invocation doesn't include your log statements - is it possible that your server logic isn't being reached?

Comment: The non-db query works fine (hello) the DB queries fail because I seem to have trouble connecting to the RDS db (what I want to debug, since the same syntax works fine with a local postgresql). Apollo dispatches to the "query resolvers" I have added that file to the question.

Comment: Well, I now moved my console log statements from the entry to the lambda function (the handler) and put them in the "apollo resolvers" and I see the logs in your Dashboard. Thanks again for the nice product! BTW, with the deploy function option, it can take 8 minutes. The Amazon AWS VSCODE plugin is a lot faster.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you like it.

I'm not sure what you mean by `the deploy function option`, and how it relates to VSCode plugins. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Serverless deploy function is supposed to be speedier since it only updates the zip and not the cloudfront stack: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy-function/

Comment: I am also experimenting not using the severless framework, but rather the VSCODE extension from AWS, but I have to do that from home, since docker is not allowed at my work.

Comment: I forked a new thread for figuring out the DB connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919590/aws-lambda-connect-via-pg-js-to-rds-postgres-database-connection-made-no-timeo

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone deploying their serverless app and receiving `{"message": "Internal server error"}` when going to their AWS endpoint**

I was running into this issue for a whole day. I made a couple of changes but I think what did it for me was including context when initializing my ApolloServer:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    ...serverConfig, // typeDefs and resolvers
    context: ({ event, context }) => ({
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context,
    }),
    playground: {
        endpoint: '/dev/graphql',
    },
});
```

See this link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/#getting-request-info

When debugging I recommend two things

1. Check your lambda function's Cloudwatch logs on AWS
2. Run `serverless offline`, go to the local endpoint and see if you get any errors (you will need to install the [serverless offline plugin](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) and include it in your `serverless.yml`)

**Also some related additional information if you're using a yarn monorepo and typescript -**

Make sure to compile and transpile the typescript code. [See this article](https://itnext.io/typescript-serverless-webpack-babel-15778188c7). My code:

- `yarn add webpack serverless-webpack`
- `yarn add -D webpack-node-externals`

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: 'node',
    mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                targets: {
                                    node: true,
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        '@babel/typescript',
                    ],
                },
                include: [__dirname],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
};
```

*serverless.yml*

```
# serverless.yml
service: apollo-lambda
plugins:
    - serverless-webpack
    - serverless-offline
custom:
    webpack:
        webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
        includeModules: true
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs12.x
functions:
    graphql:
        # this is formatted as <FILENAME>.<HANDLER>
        handler: dist/server.graphqlHandler
        environment:
            SLS_DEBUG: true
        events:
            - http:
                  path: graphql
                  method: post
                  cors: true
                  integration: lambda-proxy
            - http:
                  path: graphql
                  method: get
                  cors: true
                  integration: lambda-proxy
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true,
        "lib": ["es5"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "types": ["react", "jest"]
    }
}
```

I also added a script called `deploy` which deletes the `dist` folder, recreates the `dist` folder after compiling the typescript (see `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`), and then runs `serverless deploy`:

*package.json*

```
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "deploy": "rimraf dist && npx tsc && serverless deploy",
  },
  ...
}
```

Note: you'll need to install `rimraf` globally for the script to work (`npm install -g rimraf`)